Exporting Active Directory Users to LDAP, passwords included
Main Question: How do I get usable passwords out of an Active Directory without replicating them to a second DC?
Context:
My company has a domain controller in the cloud. When people log into the on-site wifi, a on-site Radius Server checks in with the off-site DC if their provided credentials are valid.
I want to safe the trip to the internet for every wifi authentication and run the radius server against something on-site. This "something on-site" cannot be a DC that is getting replicas from the primary cloud DC.
Ideally "something on-site" would be a simple LDAP Server that gets updates from the DC regularly. This way the authentication process which people experience stays on-site and quick.
I know i can use the Ldifde command to export selected fields and ldapadd to import them onto a on-site LDAP server. Since this does not include the password or a password hash, i am missing the fun part which makes this capability on its own pointless for the task.
I know about Mimikatz, Microsoft Identity Manager the DSInternals Powershell Module. Are there any other options I am missing?
Disclaimer: I know this topic demands respect. I know this is not the intended way to use an AD. I know in a perfect world you would not do this. This is not my idea. I appreciate any comments besides a pure "this is stupid dont do it".
Thanks!

'This "something on-site" cannot be a DC that is getting replicas from the primary cloud DC' - why not?

I'm guessing that the team that runs AD is separate and that's why it can't be a DC. If that is the case, have you tried just writing up a proposal and submitting it to that team?

You can arbitrarily extract user password hashes with the dsinternals module you mentioned. Can you explain why this doesn't meet your requirements?

@MathiasR.Jessen because the company wants to get rid of the on-site DC(s). I know that an on-site DC would be the simplest solution and probably safe a bunch of time and nerves. Like I said this is not my idea.

@mikecrowley This meets my requirements but to me seems like a lot of extra steps. It would require the radius server to support the same hashing algorithm and it would require me to manually extract the hashes and match them to the usernames i get using Ldifde. While this feels doable it certainly would not be elegant and seems like it carries a lot of potential for erros.

You could deploy PCNS and have users change their password at least once to begin using the external (RADIUS etc) product.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-identity-manager/deploying-mim-password-change-notification-service-on-domain-controller
